# Can't factor problem after trying everything

Tags: quadratics, factoring

This is the equation:

$(2a - 3b)^2 - (a+2b)^3 + 7a^2(6b - a)$

Here is what I tried:

$4a^2 - 12ab + 9b^2 -(a^3 + 6a^2b + 12ab^2 + 8b^3) + 42a^2b - 7a^3$

$4a^2 - 12ab + 9b^2 - a^3 - 6a^2b - 12ab^2 - 8b^3 + 42a^2b - 7a^3$

$4a^2 - 8a^3 - 8b^3 - 12ab + 9b^2 - 12ab^2 + 36a^2b$

$4a^2 - 8(a^3 + b^3) - 12ab + 9b^2 - 12ab^2 + 36a^2b$

$4a(a + 9ab - 3b) + 3b(3b - 4ab) - 8(a^3 + b^3)$

The answer is supposed to be:

$42ab^2 - 35b^3$

However I have no idea how to get to it, I've been trying to transform it into different ways and always end up at the same spot above.

Am I wrong in my method of factoring? Should I have done something totally different?

Comment: If $b=0$ the expression reduces to $4a^2-8a^3\,$, while the "answer" gives $0$.

Comment: I don't see any way for that answer to be correct. Your binomial expansion yields nothing close.

Comment: What if $a$ is also $0$?

Comment: The simplest way to see the answer is wrong is to see there is nothing to combine with the leading $4a^2$ to get rid of it.

Comment: @shortage_radeon:  the point of dxiv's comment is that if the original expression equals the final one they have to be equal for all values of $a,b$.  dxiv has chosen a convenient value for $b$ to show the two expressions disagree.  Yes, if $a=b=0$ they both give zero, but that doesn't prove anything.  Plugging in values can prove the expressions different, but not prove them the same.

Comment: The original expression is not homogeneous, there are terms of degree three but others of degree two. So, the original expression is wrong as typed, either an error here or one in the book/notes/site that gave the expression. I see, it ought to be $$(2a - 3b)^3 - (a+2b)^3 + 7a^2(6b - a)$$

Comment: Well the book answer is obviously wrong for many reasons.  There is no a^3 term when there should be -8a^3 and the b^3 term should be 8 and not 35.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to evaluate the expression to see that it cannot match the given answer.

Because the answer is an homogeneous cubic polynomial in $a,b$, while the expression has quadratic terms which do not simplify.

But

$$(2a - 3b)^\color{red}3 - (a+2b)^3 + 7a^2(6b - a)=42ab^2-35b^3.$$

Comment: Hmm so my textbook is incorrect then, I double checked it and yes - that's the problem and that's the answer they've given. I guess the textbook has an error, too bad I spent a lot of time trying to solve it, thanks for helping.
Apparently they printed a $(2a - 3b)^2$ instead of $(2a - 3b)^3$, thanks agian

Comment: Nobody's safe from typos :-)